# Why do I get this unexpected SQL performance gain?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is more a quiz question rather than me panicking over a deadline, however understanding how/why would no doubt let me scratch my head a little less!

So I have this UPDATE statement:

```
/*** @Table is a TABLE Variable ***/
UPDATE O
SET O.PPTime = T.PPTime
FROM @Table AS [O]
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT O.OSID, O.STID, DATEDIFF(SECOND, O.StartDateTime, O.EndDateTime) AS [PPTime]
        FROM tblO AS [O]
        INNER JOIN tblS AS [S] ON O.OSID = S.OSID
        INNER JOIN tblE AS [E] ON S.EID = E.EID
        INNER JOIN tblEF AS [EF] ON E.EFID = EF.EFID
        GROUP BY O.OSID, O.STID, O.StartDateTime, O.EndDateTime) AS [T]
ON O.OSID = T.OSID
WHERE O.PPTime IS NULL
```

The execution time is approximately 12 seconds.

Now below I have added in a small WHERE statement which does not have any impact on how many rows of data are returned to the user:

```
/*** @Table is a TABLE Variable ***/
UPDATE O
SET O.PPTime = T.PPTime
FROM @Table AS [O]
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT O.OSID, O.STID, DATEDIFF(SECOND, O.StartDateTime, O.EndDateTime) AS [PPTime]
        FROM tblO AS [O]
        INNER JOIN tblS AS [S] ON O.OSID = S.OSID
        INNER JOIN tblE AS [E] ON S.EID = E.EID
        INNER JOIN tblEF AS [EF] ON E.EFID = EF.EFID
        WHERE O.OSID >= 0       /*** Somehow fixes performance slow down! ***/
        GROUP BY O.OSID, O.STID, O.StartDateTime, O.EndDateTime) AS [T]
ON O.OSID = T.OSID
WHERE O.PPTime IS NULL
```

The execution time is now less than a second. If I run both SELECT statements individually, they execute in the same time and return the same data.

Why do I get such a performance gain?

Comment: This is because either the optimizer stumbles across a better execution plan.  One possibility is an index that gets used.  More likely is that the query no longer does a nested loop join.  You would need to look at the execution plans to understand what is happening.

Comment: If you check your actual execution plan, you will see which are the operators the query optimizer has chosen for each case. Maybe it will make sense then :)

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN` on both queries and my guess is you'll see something obvious in the reports.

Comment: Run both with Option (Recompile) at the end and see if the performance is the same. If so, the problem is to do with the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code, I noticed that adding a Primary Key and/or indexing to the table variable done the trick! One for me to remember!